# Após Login, como passar valor para a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Após realizar o login, o usuário é direcionado para a pagina `Home` e nesta pagina, gostaria de mostrar um `Label` com o código do cliente a quem esse usuario pertence.

Então, fui na tabela `AspNetUsers` adicionei uma coluna chamada `Cod_Cliente`, então no `AccountController` tentei:

```
 // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Usuário, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    //recupera as informações do usuario que corresponda ao usuario e password
                    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Usuário, model.Password);


                    //redireciona o login para a pagina que o usuario estava.
                    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    //redireciona o login para o index do controller home
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }                   
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Inválido!");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Porém, a variavel `user` recebe um objeto com os dados do usuario, mas o campo que eu preciso `Cod_Cliente` não esta entre eles.

Então tentei incluir o parâmetro no model `AccountViewModel`

```
 public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    public string Usuário { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Permanecer Conectado?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public bool Cod_Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Porem sem sucesso.

Segue abaixo a `View Index` do `HomeController`

```
    @using OneeWeb_v3.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Bem Vindo ao OneeWeb - @DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</h2>   
    <h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Cod_Cliente)</h3>
    <p class="lead">CNPJ: 054.105.671/xxxx-xx</p>
    @*<p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>*@
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
            ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
            enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
            for enjoyable, agile development.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você precisa criar esse campo na classe que representa essa tabela, caso você não tenha modificado nada no template padrão, deve ser a `ApplicationUser` (que extende a `IdentityUser`). Sugiro dar uma lida [nesse link](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2015/02/customizando-nomes-tabelas-campos-asp-net-identity/) para ter uma base.

Comment: @Alisson amigo obrigado pela dica, consegui fazer apos o login que seja retornado o valor, mas ainda nao consegui mostrar na view. obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu mudaria o seguinte;

**LoginViewModel**

```
public int Cod_Cliente { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.CodigoUser = model.Cod_Cliente;
```

**View**

```
<h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(ViewBag.CodigoUser)</h3>
```